# Strange behavior of bindToController inside Directive definition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a chat Application with Angular.js. messages stored inside an Array and i have to bind that array to the HTML view. if i click on every message, i need to an alert() fired inside the controller. my controller is like this:

```
app.controller("timelineCtrl", function ($scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.arr={};

    // this called from a socket message and pushed it's data to this array
    self.arr.push(socket_message);

}
```

I have this directive:

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope:{
            post: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="timeline-item"> Hello {{postCtrl.post}} </div>',
        controller: 'timelineCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'postCtrl',
        bindToController: true
    };
});
```

and this is my HTML view:

```
<div ng-controller="timelineCtrl as postCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="post in postCtrl.arr">
         <hello-world post='post'></hello-world>
    </div>
</div>
```

right now, with this structure, when first item goes to array everything is OK, when second item came, doesn't append to array and replaces with first item, then next items behave normal and append to array. why second item replace with first item?

This is my array log in browser console:
[image]

It seems this problem related to controller aliasing section inside directive because when i add bindToController and controllerAs: 'postCtrl', this strange behavior appears. first time i press the button HTML updates normally, but next times nothing works. i log that array and it seems when second item arrives, replaces with first item for no reason. it seems an overlapping issue or something like that.

Comment: Why are you trying to use  `$scope` and `bindToController` together in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl: $scope? where? i cant understand.

Comment: read the docs for `bindToController`. It's used for `controllerAs` which you aren't using

Comment: @charlietfl: i read all of the documents but i don't know why this happen still.

Comment: @Claies: have you any idea about this?

Comment: about what? There are different controller constructs for using $scope or controllerAs.

Comment: @charlietfl: i know, i updated my question, i use .this rather than $scope and ng-controller="timelineCtrl as postCtrl" but still i get that anomaly. Why that can happen? i even don't know Why and how. if i remove controllerAs section, this doesn't happen!

Comment: Creat a demo that replicates problem. You can't `push` to an `object` so I have no idea what is going on in your code and the issue has now changed